# CSS regarding height and scrolling

Tags: css, height, tailwind-css

Trying to learn CSS and Tailwind in general and struggling with height.

https://jsfiddle.net/7f6cd1bx/

I made a code pen above based off this https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/new-telegram-web-clone

If I were to scroll to the bottom on the list of chats, the last card only shows up partially. I would like it to show completely.

Based on what I can interpret, the list of chats section is set to `100vh`, as a result it overflows and was configured to hide it. I'm not sure how to get it to fit the given height.

What I'm really confused is, the vertical scrollbar is meant to deal with content that cannot fit, but now the vertical scrollbar itself cannot fit in the given space.

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex;` properly has been overrided by `display:block` properly for this `<div>` element:

```html
 <!-- left -->
        <div class="relative flex flex-col hidden h-full bg-white border-r border-gray-300 shadow-xl md:block transform transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out"
            style="width: 24rem">
```

try to add class `left-side-wrap` to this `<div>`

```html
 <!-- left -->
        <div class="left-side-wrap relative flex flex-col hidden h-full bg-white border-r border-gray-300 shadow-xl md:block transform transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out"
            style="width: 24rem">
```

and after that add this CSS code to make sure that `<div>` will have `display:flex;` properly:

```css
body .left-side-wrap{
  display: flex;  
}
```

Here you can check an updated Js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j1rbv7un/

Comment: wow thanks! let me try to digest what you shared, but I noticed the fiddle did not fill til the bottom, there was a little white gap there, any idea?

Comment: @bilogic  you have `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` for that `<div>` element and because of that you have those gaps

Comment: you're always welcome!

Comment: ok, I digested your findings, if you could: the better way is to change `md:block` to `md:flex` and do away with adding custom CSS as I was hoping to stick to only tailwind-css. Perhaps you can also share more on how you figured out this was the offender? That will really help me an anyone else who come across this thanks!

Comment: I was using DevTools to inspect the HTML and CSS structure and noticed that `display:flex;` properly was overridden by `display:block;` for that particular `<div>` element and once I've placed `display: flex;` into `element.style{}` section I've noticed that the `<div>` now fit the given height

Comment: I see, I'm facing the same problem with this https://jsfiddle.net/8jvzabfu I tried to apply what you shared, but no joy. If you like, I can ask a new question thank you